# How do I determine from strace output what part of my program is failing to acquire a mutex

Tags: c++, linux, mutex, strace

I'm working on an embedded Linux system (3.12.something), and our application, after some random amount of time, starts hogging the CPU. I've run `strace` on our application, and right when the problem happens, I see a lot of lines similar to this in the `strace` output:

```
[48530666] futex(0x485f78b8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <0.009002>
```

I'm pretty sure this is the smoking gun I'm looking for and there is a race of some sort. However, I now need to figure out how to identify the place in the code that's trying to get this mutex. How can I do that? Our code is compiled with GCC and has debugging symbols in it.

My current thinking (that I haven't tried yet) is to print out a string to stdout and flush before trying to grab any mutex in our system, with the expectation that the string will print right before strace complains about getting the lock ... but there are a LOT of places in the code that would have to be instrumented like this.

EDIT: Another strange thing that I just realized is that our program doesn't start hogging the CPU until some random time has passed since it was run (5 minutes to 5 hours and anywhere in between). During that time, there are *zero* `futex` syscalls happening. Why do they suddenly start? From what I've read, I think maybe they are being used properly in userspace until something fails and falls back to making a `futex()` syscall...

Any suggestions?

Comment: you might try working with gdb for this instead.  strace does have a threaded output toggle as well to give strace output broken out by pid.

Comment: How would I use gdb to find this? Can it detect this condition somehow and break automatically? (I don't want to watch for hours on end for the problem to start...)

Comment: Ok, it looks like `catch syscall 240` will work for this in gdb. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: `The feature 'catch syscall' is not supported on this architecture yet.` Doh!

Comment: The question of how to find code fails to acquire a mutex brings me to Herb Sutter's GotW thread on the subject of why that paradigm promotes brittle code. If app code is first required to get a lock, then access the data, then release...don't expect app code to do that repeatedly. Provide (i.e. replace with) an object that wraps the data being protected, so there's no option. Doing this now will drive editing by compiler complaint, but ultimately you'll have two benefits. One, app code can't skip mutex acquisition, and you have code you can intercept with a debugger for all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you perpetually and often lock a mutex for a short time from different threads, like e.g. one protecting a global logger, you might cause a so-called thread convoy. The problem doesn't occur until two threads compete for the lock. The first gets the lock and holds it for a short time, then, when it needs the lock a second time, it gets preempted because the second one is waiting already. The second one does the same. The timeslice available to each thread is suddenly reduced to the time between two lock attempts, causing many context switches and the according slowdown. Further, all but one thread is always blocked on the mutex, effectively disabling any parallel execution.

In order to fix this, make your threads cooperate instead of competing for resources. For above example of a logger, consider e.g. a lock-free queue for the entries or separate queues for each thread using thread-local storage.

Concerning the futex() calls, the idea is to poll an atomic flag and after some rotations use the actual OS mutex. The atomic flag is available without the expensive switch between user-space and kernel-space. For longer breaks, using the kernel preemption (with `futex()`) avoids blocking the CPU with polling. This explains why the program doesn't need any `futex()` calls in normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

You, basically need to generate core file at this moment.

Then you could load program+core in GDB and look at it

`man gcore`

or

`generate-core-file`

> During that time, there are zero futex syscalls happening. Why do they suddenly start?

This is due to the fact that uncontested mutex, implemented via futex, doesn't make a system call, only atomic increment, purely in user space. Only CONTESTED lock is visible as system call